# How can I open a vim fold so that it is not affected by `foldclose=all`?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, neovim, folding

In my config file I have `set foldclose=all` so that folds get automatically
closed upon cursor leaving them. However, sometimes, I want a specific fold not
to close for a while.

Because folds below `foldlevel=#` and folds smaller than `foldminlines=#` are
not affected by `foldclose=all`, there must exist a list of folds that
`foldclose=all` doesn't work on.

I want to create a mapping that puts a particular fold (the one where my cursor
is) to that list so that it's temporarily not affected by `foldclose=all`,
*i.e.*, so that it doesn't close automatically even though `foldclose` is set to
`all`.

How can I add folds to those that `foldclose=all` doesn't work on?

I did not find anything in the [neovim documentation on
folds](https://neovim.io/doc/user/fold.html) and tried to make a workaround by
using `:mkview` but then I would have to have `:loadview` triggered every time a
fold is closed, which I don't know how to do (and doesn't seem to be feasible
and efficient). I work in c++ and my default settings are `foldlevel=1`,
`foldmethod=syntax`, `foldopen=hor`.

Comment: `:help 'foldclose'` says `When set to "all", a fold is closed when the cursor isn't in it and its level is higher than 'foldlevel'.  Useful if you want folds to automatically close when moving out of them.` So you would need a fold with level smaller than `foldlevel` to not be affected by `foldclose=all`.

Comment: Folds smaller than Foldminlines are also not affected. The answer is not in documentation, I am quite sure. I was hoping for an expert to tell me how to utilize neovim source code. Folds below specified level are excepted from foldclose so I want to add new folds to that exception list.

Answer (score 0):

Vim defaults to `foldlevel=0`. Consider setting it in vimrc to 2 and setting the fold you want left open to 1.

I use fold markers, and the way to set fold levels is to add a number to the marker:

```
" I'm fold 1 {{{1
" End fold 1 }}}

" I'm fold 2 {{{2
" End fold 2 }}}
```

If you're using some other fold method, I'm not sure how to set the level of a particular fold. I can't seem to locate that information in the docs.

An alternative, if you truly do want it open permanently as the title of your question says, is to delete the fold.

Comment: Note that folds also get a level via "nesting", so a fold inside a fold with level `N` has level `N+1`.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Really? I've never seemed to be able to get that to work, but it's been a while. I'll have to try it again.

Then again, I like explicitness.

Comment: I spoke without checking the docs, but I’m fairly certain that’s correct.